# Effective field theory odd dimension operators

Tags: symmetry, conservation-laws, dimensional-analysis, beyond-the-standard-model, effective-field-theory

In the Standard Model Effective Field Theory,

$$L_{EFT} = L_{SM} + \sum_{d=5}^{\infty}\sum_{i} \frac{c_i^{(d)}}{\Lambda_{i}^{d-4}} \mathcal{O}_i^{(d)},$$

typically, the odd dimension terms are omitted because they violate the conservation of number of lepton and baryon. How can one verify this last statement?

Comment: Have you tried writing an odd-dimension term that conserves lepton and baryon numbers?

Comment: Hi @MauroGiliberti, this is exactly what I'm trying to understand, how do you check this and how do you see that it violates this QM number.

Answer (score 2):

[This paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1604.05726) (and its references such as [this one in Appendix A](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.4231)) contain a general proof.

It shows that if you have an operator that violates $B$ of an amount $\Delta B$ and $L$ of an amount $\Delta L$, then the dimension of the operator has the same parity as $(\Delta B - \Delta L)/2$.

In particular from this it follows that the only operators that do not violate $B$ and $L$, that is those for which $\Delta B = \Delta L = 0$, must have even dimension.